# .htaccess redirect subdirectory to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to `rewrite` url like:
http://domain.com/index.php/subdirectory/subdirectory/
to:
http://domain.com/index.php

My rewrite rule look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php$  [L]
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)
```

will always been false, you don't need it. Just use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php  [L]
```